# Swift Searchbar App crashing while filtering 2 arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, uisearchbar

I'm populating a tableview with two arrays. I keep getting an error after about typing two characters into the search bar that the app is crashing because the array counts are not the same. I've been experimenting with this for a while but I can't figure out a solution. The posts similar to this have 2 arrays, but for each 'set' I have an array with the data(data and PostUser), and an array with the same data, but filtered(filteredData, and PostUserFiltered. I couldn't apply their solutions to mine.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SearchPostsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var data:[String] = []

    var filteredData: [String] = [String]()
    var idArray:[String] = []
    var postUser:[String] = []
    var postUserFiltered: [String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ourId = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SearchIds")
        print("Our ids\(ourId!)")
        self.idArray = ourId! as! [String]
        for singleId in idArray {

            Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts").child("\(singleId)/message").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if let test = snapshot.value as? String!{
                            self.data.append(test)
                            print(test)
                            self.filteredData = self.data
                            print("data: \(self.filteredData)")
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    })
                }
        self.filteredData = self.data
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for singleId in idArray {

            Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts").child("\(singleId)/username").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let test = snapshot.value as? String!{
                    self.postUser.append(test)
                    print(test)
                    self.postUserFiltered = self.postUser
                    print("data: \(self.postUserFiltered)")
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
        }
        self.postUserFiltered = self.postUser
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

            cell.textLabel?.text = self.filteredData[indexPath.row]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.postUserFiltered[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postUserFiltered.count
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }
        ////////////////for the username now
        postUserFiltered = searchText.isEmpty ? postUser : postUser.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: They never say at what line the app crahshes or where an error occurs.

Comment: Can you show us the error message and what line it's crashing on? It's most likely that the array index is out of bounds.

Comment: @Echizzle It crashes in the: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return postUserFiltered.count
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is because there is a mismatch in the lengths of your 2 arrays i.e filteredData and postUserFiltered.

the reason is that you are filtering your filteredData based on if it contains the text that's entered in the search field Vs. only filtering the postUser and taking his corrosponding post while eleminating others.

I would suggest you to use a dictionary instead of 2 different arrays where the key would be postUser and the value would be Data.

you can filter the dictionary based on the key thus preserving correspondence of postUser with correct data

you can use the below code if you still wanna use 2 arrays; I have modified your code for you.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class SearchPostsController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var data:[String] = []

    var filteredData: [String] = []
    var idArray:[String] = []
    var postUser:[String] = []
    var postUserFiltered: [String] = []
    var mapping: [String:Int] = [:]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let ourId = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "SearchIds")
        print("Our ids\(ourId!)")
        self.idArray = ourId! as! [String]
        var index = 0;
        for singleId in idArray {

            Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts").child("\(singleId)/message").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    if let test = snapshot.value as? String!{
                            self.data.append(test)
                            print(test)
                            self.filteredData = self.data
                            print("data: \(self.filteredData)")
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    })
                }
        self.filteredData = self.data
        ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        for singleId in idArray {

            Database.database().reference().child("\(UserData().mySchool!)/posts").child("\(singleId)/username").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
                if let test = snapshot.value as? String!{
                    self.postUser.append(test)
                    print(test)
                    self.mapping[test] = index;
                    self.postUserFiltered = self.postUser
                    print("data: \(self.postUserFiltered)")
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            })
          index += 1;
        }
        self.postUserFiltered = self.postUser
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "cell")

            cell.textLabel?.text = self.data[self.mapping[self.postUserFiltered[indexPath.row]]]
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = self.postUserFiltered[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if let postUserFiltered = self.postUserFiltered{
          return postUserFiltered.count
        }
        return 0
    }
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

        filteredData = searchText.isEmpty ? data : data.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }
        ////////////////for the username now
        postUserFiltered = searchText.isEmpty ? postUser : postUser.filter { (item: String) -> Bool in
            // If dataItem matches the searchText, return true to include it
            return item.range(of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
        }

        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
        searchBar.text = ""
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        self.searchBar.showsCancelButton = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: This still crashes at the numberOfRowsInSection with postUserFiltered.count

Comment: I have edited it, try it now. Ill tell you what the issue was when this works

Comment: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String]'         is the error from the line in '        if let postUserFiltered = self.postUserFiltered{' ...Thanks for all your replies so far!